# Error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request

Tags: asp.net, web-config, iis-7.5

I have copied a client's web application to my `C:\inetpub\wwwroot`.

I aslo run Aspnet_regiis.exe -i to solve a previous error I was having

Now I have this error:

Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Source Error:

```
Line 31:     
Line 32:     <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
Line 33:     <authentication mode="Forms">
Line 34:       <forms loginUrl="~/Default.aspx" timeout="2880" />
Line 35:     </authentication>
```

Source File: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\site\web.config    Line: 33

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18408

I have tried to run the application: `http://localhost/site/Default.aspx`. How do I fix the error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to your IIS management console, find the directory called site under the Default Web Site (which is under the Sites node), right click on site and choose Convert to Application.